Fantasy book about a young sister and brother who leave their village; the sister becomes a dragon rider
I read this story while I was in Middle School, so 2008-2011.It's Kinda vague but the Book was about a young girl and her brother are forced to leave their village. After leaving their village they come across these mud plains in which they have to be saved by the people who live there. They then have to take a boat made for the mud to a rope which will take them to the above world (They did not know they were underground for some reason.) After getting up there it isn't long before they are taken by these agents of some organization. The brother is taken to a training facility where he trains and is tortured to try and make a dragon egg hatch. Supposedly the fear of the rider is what creates the bond but females cannot form a bond. The sister as a result is sent to a mine because she is considered a distraction for her brother and can compromise his soon to be loyalty. This is where you find the first instance of technology, and its a perimeter fence. All prisoners at the mines where collars that blow up when you cross them. The sister escapes the mines with the help from another girl who lost her brother to the group, who dies in her stead.
She goes to save her brother, and when she finds him by the egg beaten. At this point the general forces the brother to whip her. Once he does this the egg hatches and bonds with the sister. The general tries to kill her in response and she escapes with the dragon. Her brother in jealous rage, turns on her and helps the general.
Sorry for the rant, its what I remember from years ago. I never got to read the second book because it was lost and I always wanted to finish the series.

Not a rant... Rant implies anger... this is more of an info dump... or a wall of text.
Some paragraphs might make it easier to read. But its not bad.
